# Entity Framework only with stored procedures

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures

i have a question about the reasonableness of using entity framework only with stored procedures in our scenario.

We plan to have an N-tier architecutre, with UI, BusinessLayer (BLL), DataAccessLayer(DAL) and a BusinessObjectDefinitions(BOD) layer. The BOD layer is known by all other layers and the results from executes queries in the DAL should be transformed into Objects (definied in the BOD) before passing into the BLL.

We will only use stored procedures for all CRUD methods.
So in case of a select stored procedure, we would add a function import, create a complex type and when we execute the function, we tranform the values of the complex type into a class of BOD and pass that to the BLL.
So basicly, we have no Entities in the Model, just Complex types, that are transformed into Business Objects.

I'm not sure if that all makes sense, since in my opinion, we lose a lot of the benefit, EF offers.

Or am i totally wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not use EF if all I was just using was stored procs.

Personally, I'd look at something like PetaPoco, Massive or even just straight Ado.Net

**EDIT**

Here's an example of PetaPoco consuming SPs and outputting custom types

http://weblogs.asp.net/jalpeshpvadgama/archive/2011/06/20/petapoco-with-stored-procedures.aspx

Answer (score 4):

I disagree with both of the existing answers here. Petapoco is great, but I think the EF still offers a number of advantages.

Petapoco works great (maybe even better than the EF) for executing simple stored procedures that read a single entity or a list of entities. However, once you've read the data and need to begin modifying it, I feel this is where the EF is the clear winner.

To insert/update data with petapoco you'll need to manually call the insert/update stored procedure using:

```
db.Execute("EXEC spName @param1 = 1, @param2 = 2")
```

Manually constructing the stored procedure call and declaring all the parameters gets old very fast when the insert/update stored procedures insert rows with more than just a couple of columns. This gets even worse when calling update stored procedures that implement optimistic concurrency (i.e. passing in the original values as parameters).

You also run the risk of making a typo in your in-lined stored procedure call, which very likely will not be caught until runtime.

Now compare this to the entity framework: In the EF I would simply map my stored procedure to my entity in the edmx. There's less risk of a typo, since the entity framework tools will automatically generate the mapping by analyzing my stored procedure.

The entity framework also will handle optimistic concurrency without any problems. Finally, when it comes time to save my changes the only step is to call:

```
entities.SaveChanges()
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree, if you rely on stored procedures for all CRUD methods, then there is no need to use EF.

Answer (score 0):

I use EF to map stored procedure calls as our DAL. It saves time in writing your DAL by mapping the functions. We are not using LINQ to SQL as much, as our DBA does not want direct data table access.

Comment: How did this approach workout for you? I am in the same boat and just wanted to make sure if there are any specific scenarios I should keep in mind while creating stored procs, calling them from EF etc. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!