# Potential risks with using Entity Framework with stored procedure with ONLY execute permissions to the SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

In my new project, the application SQL Server user Id only has 'Execute' permissions to the database.

I am planning to use Entity Framework with WebAPI and use stored procedures on the SQL Server side to get data to my AngularJS Website. DBA doesn't allow table access so writing Linq is out of question.

I have tested a basic query (a `select *`) using below code and everything works fine:

```
var Data = PreEmploymentEntity.Database.SqlQuery<PortalUser>("Exec Test").ToList();
return Ok(Data);
```

Are there anything I should consider or any risks associated with design if I go forward with this?

I found this link- [Entity Framework only with stored procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427208/entity-framework-only-with-stored-procedures) but I am not sure if they are stuck with only 'execute' permissions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is it depends. Your user can access database objects using stored procedures without any permission to the objects inside them if one of the following is true:

- your procedures are using [EXECUTE AS Clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-clause-transact-sql), the user used
  in this clause have all the necessary permissions
- the procedure owner is the same as the owner of all the objects
  accessed by this procedure (see [Ownership Chains](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676(v=sql.105).aspx)) and there is no use of dynamic code within it.

In both cases there is another limitation:

- stored procedure must use only DML (for example, TRUNCATE TABLE is
  not DML)

If you should use DDL, you can sign your sp with the [certificate](http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html#Certificates)

The last thing, signing with a certificate, permits you to do everything through the procedures, but it's the most difficult way to give the permissions.